# "Filling" a plastic cup with static electricity

Tags: electrostatics

Okay, so when I was a fourth grader back in 2013 a man came to our school to give us a lesson on static electricity. He did all of the usual things like making people's hair stand up on end and other stuff like that. But what was really interesting was when asked for volunteers. I was one of 7 or so guys that got picked and went up to the front. So he took out this contraption that seemed to be made of a wheel about a foot in diameter with a hand crank and then there were two wires that weren't connected to each other protruding out the one side and angled downward. So he took this plastic cup that looked exactly like the one I drink out of all the time and he "filled" it with electricity by placing the two wires inside of it and cranking the handle. When he was finished he asked the volunteers to hold hands and form a chain. He told the kid at the one end to wet two of his fingers and this man very carefully placed the cup in the hand of the kid at the other end. When the kid placed his wet fingers into the cup the whole chain got zapped. This shock was so intense that I think it was worse than any capacitor, cow fence (I have a friend who peed on a cow fence and you can guess what happened next) shocks I've ever gotten. I felt really tired the rest of the day.

So how does this work? Is the cup itself holding the charge. I've done my research on this and can't find anything about this. Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: There is a lot of material on static electricity.  It is excellent that you have done some research and maybe you can briefly describe in your answer what you have found and why you think it does not apply to the situation at hand.

Comment: As someone already mentioned, the contraption could have been the Wimshurst Machine. The plastic cup should form a primitive capacitor, such as Leyden jar. Hand of the man and afterwards the lucky student would form one capacitor plate, which would explain replacing his hand with student's hand carefully (to preserve the charge). Currently it escapes me what medium would form the other capacitor plate. Are you sure the cup was empty, and not filled with water?

Comment: It might have been filled with water. I do remember his finger being wet but I don't remember when he got it wet.